# redirect with an error message using passport authenticate callback

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm using passport with oauth2 strategy and am trying to find a way to pass along the error message to the error page which is a .ejs template file.
Is there a way to pass on the actual error to this /error.ejs page ? If not is there a way to not redirect and just console log the error. I just need to see what the error is before it redirects ?

```
router.get(
  process.env.CALLBACK,
  passport.authenticate("oauth2", {
    failureRedirect: "/error",
    successRedirect: "/",
  })
);

router.get("/error", (req, res) => {
  console.log("req = ", req.error);
  res.render("error");
});
```

Nothing is coming back as far as error. I event tried message

Comment: Is there anyone that knows how to pass back error data to the failureRedirect ?

Comment: try to look at that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46768696/username-or-password-failure-message-in-passport-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the source code there are 2 approaches to this.

### Method 1:

- setting `failureMessage: true` in the authenticate params
- getting the error message in the error path from `req.session.messages`

```
router.get(
  process.env.CALLBACK,
  passport.authenticate("oauth2", {
    failureRedirect: "/error",
    failureMessage: true,
    successRedirect: "/",
  })
);

router.get("/error", (req, res) => {
  console.log("req = ", req.session.messages);
  res.render("error");
});
```

(ref: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L27)

---

### Method 2:

- instead of passing an object with params, you can supply a custom callback function:

```
router.get(
  process.env.CALLBACK,
  function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate("oauth2", function (err, user, info, status) {
      if (err) {
        // do something with the error
        console.error("error: ", err);
      }
      // success
      res.redirect("/");
    })(req, res, next);
  }
);
```

(ref: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L34)