# How do i sync Data between Worker Threads / Clusters in Node.js

Tags: node.js, node-worker-threads

I have a question how do i "sync" data, for example userdata in cache for all workers / cluster in a node js Cluster Thread?

Like a static variable but for all threads.

for example a static string[] is the "same" in worker thread 1 and 2

the array is getting edited in the cluster thread so its not so usefull if the main thread is giving them it over.

Comment: Can you use the file system or a database?

Comment: look at this [worker.workerData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46768696/username-or-password-failure-message-in-passport-js) maybe it can help you.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen of course but if i want to make a cache that is a cache for example.

Comment: @AbdurrahimAhmadov the link is wrong but i looked it up, it is "good" but its only possible during creation, so its almost useless.